# Android UI Menu

Tags: android, user-interface, menu

How To Create UI Menu Like Below

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything? care to share any more details?

Comment: means you want to put the "circle" indicator showing 1 2 3 4 , etc. ? or you want to show icon view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dashboard Layout

Tutorial:

http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-implementing-a-dashboard-activity/

Source:

https://gist.github.com/882650

An Example:

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/activity_home.xml
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/HomeActivity.java
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/DashboardFragment.java

Comment: No Action Bar İn My Project, Android sdk ver 2.2

Comment: What? If you ask a cryptic question, expect assumptions in the answers

Comment: The example doesn't actually cover adding an actionbar.

Comment: maybe because he doesn't mention ActionBar in his question

Comment: Which is my point, I read "No Action Bar in My Project..." as saying that the tutorial isn't correct for what he's after.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the scrollable pager and the indicator (1, 2, 3, 4...)

If so, there are many ViewPager library available on Github. I know two of them are:

- android-viewflow: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow
- Android-ViewPagerIndicator: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

If you want to find good Android UI library to reuse in your project, check our this "Android UI Patterns" app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns